# WordPress Menu Dropdown Not Dropping down

Tags: css, menu

For some reason I cannot get the drop down to appear on this site: http://a.dev200.com/cflow/
It works fine on mobile screen size, just not on desktop screen size.
Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an "**overflow: hidden**" in "**megaMenu**" div.

Try to fix it or add this css code:

```
#megaMenu.megaFullWidth { overflow: visible; }
```